# Check external link status before updating

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, updates

I am using the below piece to update multiple links on an Excel workbook.
However currently, if one of the links does not work, it simply flags an error in the code.

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
```

How can I do the following:

```
'Pseudocode
If link is valid Then
    Update
Else
    Go to next link
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the links using the [Workbook.LinkSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821922.aspx) property, which returns an array of link names, and then you can update each link individually, while ignoring errors:

```
Sub SafeUpdateLink(LinkName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=LinkName
End Sub

Sub UpdateAllLinks
    Dim x As Variant
    For Each x In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
        SafeUpdateLink x
    Next
End Sub
```